# MapBox-GL Source / addSource bug

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm getting this error `**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sources' of undefined**` (mapbox-gl.js:4) when trying to load a tile as a `mapbox-gl` source.

```
<div id='map' style='height:500px;width:700px;'>    
</div>

<script>
    var accessToken='<my access token>'
    mapboxgl.accessToken = accessToken;
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-styles/styles/outdoors-v4.json', //stylesheet location
      center: [-34.6, -58.4],
      zoom: 11
    });
    var sourceObj = new mapboxgl.Source({
      type: 'vector',
      url: 'mapbox://<some map id>'
    });
    map.addSource('test',sourceObj);
</script>
```

If I don't load any source, everything works well. This happens with the `0.2.1` and `0.2.2` versions of the API. I tried with different tiles and I get the same problem.

Any clue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/729) in Mapbox GL which we will fix. Thanks for the report.

Comment: Is this still a bug? i'm having trouble running the addsource() provided snippet from MapBox's [documentation page] (https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#VideoSource)